react-beautiful-dnd list not reordering
I am trying to make an app with react-beautiful-dnd that allows you to drag courses between semesters. I believe everything in the handleDrag function is correct, and the I am printing the data after going through the function and it is correct. The only problem is that the items snap back to their initial position after dragging.
handleDrag
`const handleDragAndDrop = (results: DropResult) => {
const { source, destination, type } = results
console.log(results)
    if (!destination) return;

    if (
        source.droppableId === destination.droppableId &&
        source.index === destination.index
    )
        return;

    if (type === "semester") {
        const reorderedSemesters = [...semesters]
        const semesterSourceIndex = source.index
        const semesterDestinationIndex = destination.index
        const [removedSemester] = reorderedSemesters.splice(semesterSourceIndex, 1)
        reorderedSemesters.splice(semesterDestinationIndex, 0, removedSemester)

        return setSemesters(reorderedSemesters)
    }


    const courseSourceIndex = source.index
    const courseDestinationIndex = destination.index

    const semesterSourceIndex = semesters.findIndex((s) => s.title === source.droppableId)
    const semesterDestinationIndex = semesters.findIndex((s) => s.title === destination.droppableId)

    const newSourceCourses = [...semesters[semesterSourceIndex].courses]
    const newDestinationCourses = source.droppableId !== destination.droppableId ? [...semesters[semesterDestinationIndex].courses] : newSourceCourses
    console.log(courseSourceIndex, courseDestinationIndex)

    const [deletedItem] = newSourceCourses.splice(courseSourceIndex, 1)
    console.log(deletedItem, newSourceCourses)
    newDestinationCourses.splice(courseDestinationIndex, 0, deletedItem)

    console.log(newSourceCourses, newDestinationCourses)
    const newSemesters = [...semesters]

    newSemesters[semesterSourceIndex] = {
        ...semesters[semesterSourceIndex],
        courses: newSourceCourses
    }
    newSemesters[semesterDestinationIndex] = {
        ...semesters[semesterDestinationIndex],
        courses: newDestinationCourses
    }
    console.log("right before updating state", newSemesters)
    return setSemesters(newSemesters)
}`

